# Customize the AVRO file generated by Sqoop

Tags: sqoop, avro

I am successfully able to generate an avro file from sqoop directly.

However when I look at the schema definition of the generated avro file I see

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "sqoop_import_QueryResult",
  "doc" : "Sqoop import of QueryResult",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "blabla",
    "type" : [ "string", "null" ],
    "columnName" : "blabla",
    "sqlType" : "12"
  }, {
    "name" : "blabla",
    "type" : [ "string", "null" ],
    "columnName" : "blabla",
    "sqlType" : "12"
  }
}
```

I wonder if I could change the `name` and the `type` to something more meaningful than `sqoop_import_queryResult` and `Sqoop import of QueryResult`.

is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that this is easy and its quote possible. in your sqoop command just pass a "--classname" whatever you put after this will become the name of the avro schama.